# Some tips on 3D Trig?

Tags: trigonometry

I understand this isn't a MATHS question specifically, however, sometimes I have trouble identifying when to use 3D trig, and trouble with it in general. Can some of the experienced/advanced people provide me with any information? ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is a Maths question. What three dimensional (3D) trigonometry means is just a twist of the usual trigonometric functions; sine, cosine and tangent, and how you can view all the plane parts in a 3D figure. Thus, you use 3D trig to identify 2 or more linking triangles in the 3D figure, for example, in a pyramid. The first thing you need to do is to identify the right angles in your figure.